# Virtualization Ubuntu guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, guest-os

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop (i7 ivy bridge 32GB mem) and run a one or two Ubuntu guests.

Is there a step by step guide to help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to go with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

If you are new to virtualization it shouldn't be too difficult, but just in case:

1. Click "New" (Badge looking Icon)
2. Give it a name, select "Linux" and under that select "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu (64-bit)" and click "Next"
3. Allocate the amount of memory you are willing to dedicate to the guests (make sure you leave enough for the host machine) and click "Next"
4. Select "create a new virtual hard drive now" and click "Next"
5. Select "VDI" and click "Next"
6. Select "Dynamically allocated" and click "Next"
7. Give it a name, select the maximum size, and click "Next"
8. You should now be out of the wizard. Select the machine you just created and click "Settings" (looks like a gear)
9. Under the Storage tab, click on "Controller: IDE" and click the little DVD, and select "Choose Disk"
10. Find your .iso of choice and click open.
11. Click "Okay" and you should be set.
12. Select the machine and click "Start"
13. Install Ubuntu like you normally would.
14. Rinse and repeat! (or you can right click on the machine and select "Clone")

Hope this helps!